# What should be done about properly answered non-notable old questions?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

Example : [Did Nazis use alternatives to Zyklon B?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/did-nazis-use-alternatives-to-zyklon-b)

On one hand, it's NOT notable, by any stretch ("according to my dad").

On the other hand, it's already well-answered, a while back. So the main reason to VTC as not notable (will distract site resources on non-notable claims) seems to not matter anymore.

**UPDATE**: This is just an example that made me ask the question. That specific question may have been notable from other users' POV. *What I'm asking is, "assuming the old question is NOT notable, without dispute...".*

Comment: "according to my dad" does not mean "only according to my dad". I always assumed that question was notable.

Comment: @Sklivvz - "according to my dad" means that no other evidence of notability was presented.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to provide evidence of notability unless there's doubt about it.

Here's how notability rules work:

[image: notability flowchart]

So to answer your question, you can follow the flowchart starting at "Does a quick Google search...?" :-)

---

No matter how old the question is, if it's not notable, according to the flowchart and to your personal judgement, vote to close. Similarly vote to reopen if necessary.

If a question is exceptional, in your opinion, for example because it's highly upvoted (or in other ways "special") you can flag it as well as voting so mods can consider locking it for historical reasons ("This question is not a good example of an on-topic question for this site, but...")

Comment: This is an amazing chart, but IMHO this answers a completely different question  (how do I tell if something is notable), and not "if a question is given to be NOT notable, but is already answered, what should I do". I guess it's my fault for picking a bad example for my question that you consider to be notable.

Comment: @DVK I think the same workflow applies in both cases.

Comment: meaning that, if it's red "NOT NOTABLE" rectangle, you VTC, even if it has a good answer? If so, please add that explicitly to your answer and i'll mark accepted.

Comment: @DVK if you notice, you can't get to "NOT NOTABLE" without passing by "Vote to close if open" :-)

Comment: guess I didn't notice the arrow direction. If that's the case, I would actually suggest reversing it - the VTC should be AFTER determining it's not notable in the process?

Comment: Is there room to add a minor exception? We've seen questions along the lines of "My mother once told me...", but no notability links. We've then had comments from different users saying "Yes. I heard the same from my aunt." I consider that sufficiently notable. (Notability links are still preferred, because they allow appropriate context to better determine the intended meaning of the claim.)

Comment: I would consider that "evidence of notability found"